# Memory optimization while downloading and saving data to s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
filename ="test.zip"
url = "some url"
data= requests.get(url, stream= True)
f= BytesIO()
f.write(data.content)
try:
   s3_r = boto3.resource('s3')
   s3_r.Object(bucket,filename).put(body= f.getvalue())
   return filename
except:
      print('failed')
```

Note: The zip file is greater than 1GB
my code is working fine but its taking a lot of memory, need to optimize the code that memory usage should not be greater then 200mb

[image]

**Found below code for Chunk**

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter below
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                # If you have chunk encoded response uncomment if
                # and set chunk_size parameter to None.
                #if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename
```

but not able save f.write(chunk) to s3 bucket

Comment: why are you writing to a `BytesIO` object, and then simply doing `f.getvalue()`?? why not just use `data.content`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand, you know that the request you sent returns a `.zip` file? Or are you trying to *create* a zip file?

Comment: Yes request returns a zip file.

Comment: zip file is more than 1GB can we download it in chunk and than save it to s3?

Comment: probably you should use `.get(url, stream=True)`, then `data.raw` will be a file object, can the boto3 `Object` API accept a file-like object? If so, this may be much more memory efficient

Comment: Have you considered downloading the whole file to disk, then using `s3.upload_file()` to upload it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i have tried it, it reduces half of the memory but i need to restrict the memory usage regardless of file size

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is restriction, cannot download it to disk need to save it in memory in chunks